# How to see total game play time?

Tags: elite-dangerous

is there any menu in which I can see my total gameplay time? I suppossed it will be in the Stats tab but I was wrong.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no "official" way to see your total play time.  Neither the game itself or the iOS companion app show this information.

However, the information is recorded as I have "snooped" at the data received by the iOS app and seen it in there.  The process is complicated, the data is not too easily readable and Frontier don't approve of people accessing the data, so I'm not going to explain the process.

However, Frontier have been asking the community recently what uses they may make out of an official API (way to access the game data) that would allow people to create their own companion tools for the game.  I would expect that the ability to see your total play time will come at some point in the future.

Personally, I don't really want to know what mine is.  I expect it amounts to more time than I spend with my family in a year....